# Simplest Lazy function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

I'm having a tough time understanding laziness.

Can someone help me understand why my function below is not lazy

```
(defn my-red
    ([f coll] (my-red f (first coll) (rest coll) ))
    ([f init coll] 
      (let [mr (fn [g i c d] 
            (if (empty? c) d 
        (recur  g (g  i (first c)) (rest c)  (conj d (g  i (first c)) ))))] 
    (lazy-seq (mr f init coll [])))))
```

whereas this example given on clojure.org/lazy is

```
(defn filter
  "Returns a lazy sequence of the items in coll for which
  (pred item) returns true. pred must be free of side-effects."
  [pred coll]
  (let [step (fn [p c]
                 (when-let [s (seq c)]
                   (if (p (first s))
                     (cons (first s) (filter p (rest s)))
                     (recur p (rest s)))))]
    (lazy-seq (step pred coll))))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The laziness in `filter` comes from the call to `filter` in the `if` branch of the recursive loop. That's where the code hits another `lazy-seq` and stops evaluating the seq until another element is requested.

Your implementation of `my-red` hits a call to `lazy-seq` one and only one time, meaning that your seq is either not evaluated at all or completely evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

The mr function will just recur through the whole of coll. Perhaps your indentation is misleading you. correctly indented, and with some useless parameters removed the function looks something like this:

```
(defn my-red
  ([f coll] (my-red f (first coll) (rest coll) ))
  ([f init coll] 
     (let [mr (fn [i c d] 
                (if (empty? c)
                  d 
                  (recur (f i (first c))
                         (rest c)
                         (conj d (f i (first c))))))] 
       (lazy-seq (mr init coll [])))))
```

Basically, you're wrapping (lazy-seq) around the mr function, which does all the work in one big recur loop.

Answer (score 2):

All `lazy-seq` does is take its argument and delay execution of it.  In order to produce a true lazy sequence, every link must be wrapped in a lazy-seq call.  The "granularity" of the lazyness is how much work is done between calls to `lazy-seq`.  The one way to get around this is to use the higher level functions that return a lazy seq.

Additionally, tail recursion and lazyness are mutually exclusive.  This does not cause stack overflows because at each step, the recursive call is wrapped up into a lazy seq and returned.  If the caller then tries to evaluate the lazy seq, the recursive call is called, but it is being called by the original caller of the sequence function, not the sequence function itself, which means that the stack doesn't grow.  This is somewhat similar to the idea of implementing optimized tail recursion via trampolines (see Clojure's `trampoline` function).

Here is a version that is lazy:

```
(defn my-red
  ([f coll] (my-red f (first coll) (rest coll) ))
  ([f init coll] 
   (let [mr (fn mr [g i c] 
              (if (empty? c)
                nil
                (let [gi (g  i (first c))]
                  (lazy-seq (cons gi (mr g gi (rest c)))))))] 
     (lazy-seq (mr f init coll)))))
```

Note how each run of `mr` immediately returns either nil or a lazy seq, and the recursive call is from within the `lazy-seq` call.